# Markers that affect intensity of the imperative mood

Tags: syntax, semantics, grammar, mood, imperative

I'm working on a project that explores how imperative mood varies in 'intensity'.

For example, one can 'soften' the tone of a directive by including the speaker in the command:

> "**Let's** go to school" is 'softer' than "Go to school"

Or by starting with the verb 'Try':

> "**Try** working harder" is 'softer' than "Work harder".

Are there any other quantifiable ways of influencing the tone of a directive, either way?

Comment: The first example could be cohortative mood. I'm not sure how the second might be analyzed

Comment: Yes, 1st-person inclusive _let_ -imperatives have that effect; probably because compliance involves joint action by speaker and addressee(s), where I commit myself to the action and seek your agreement. English doesn't have mood (other than that marked by modal auxiliaries and the so-called 'irrealis' mood). The imperative is a clause type where the verb is in plain form (infinitive). Likewise, "try" is not a modal auxiliary verb, but cf. the modal "You should try working harder"

Comment: Thanks for these quick responses. @BillJ: If "Try" in the second example doesn't function as a modal auxiliary verb, what function does it perform? Thanks again.

Comment: "Try" simply becomes the verb in the imperative and "working" is the complement.

Comment: If the project is formally described in terms of "the imperative mood" in English, then it's time for a rethink on terminology. You're doing pragmatics, not syntax.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks for your insight. This isn't the formal name for the project, just the name of this post.